# move column cell up if null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to format the result set from a sql statement to put into the command of a crystal report. If the row cell is  null I need it to move up. I know this is not what sql is made for, but it is the client spec. I have a example here, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76999/11

this is what I have now

[1 http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/7186/have.jpg](http://img259.imageshack.us/img259/7186/have.jpg)

and this is what I need

[1 http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/465/needd.jpg](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/465/needd.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't that be better handled in Crystal Reports using the PreviousRecord and NextRecord functionality?

Comment: @user973671 - Your fiddle does not match the screenshots: the top row's `TAXCODE` is `adj`, not null. What do you mean by "moved up"? Eliminated from the result set, as the screenshots suggest, or placed in a different order (say, at the top or bottom)? If excluding these rows from the result is acceptable, is there some reason you don't just include `WHERE TAXCODE IS NOT NULL` (or `OWNERTAX` if that's the field which indicates when a row should be "moved up") in the query?

Comment: Are these ordered somehow?  Can there be multiple NULLs in the first two columns on different rows?

Comment: @Esoteric - A where is not null will exclude the other values, I cannot have that, they must still be in the result set. If the first value of a column is null I need It to move up. Thanks

Comment: @Gordon - There shouldn't be any nulls on the first row. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and let me know how it works for you:

```
WITH DATA1 (ID, TaxCode)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TaxCode desc) AS ID, A.TaxCode FROM Table A)

, DATA2 (ID, OwnerTax)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ownertax desc) AS ID, A.OwnerTax FROM Table A)

, DATA3 (ID, OwnerOther)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OwnerOther desc) AS ID, A.OwnerOther FROM Table A)

, DATA4 (ID, DEDCode)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DEDCode desc) AS ID, A.DEDCode FROM Table A)

SELECT DATA1.TaxCode, DATA2.OwnerTax, DATA3.OwnerOther, DATA4.DEDCode
FROM DATA1 
LEFT JOIN DATA2 ON DATA1.ID = DATA2.ID
LEFT JOIN Data3 ON DATA1.ID = DATA3.ID
LEFT JOIN Data4 ON DATA1.ID = DATA4.ID
```

The below SQL will work on the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76999/11 if you copy and paste it directly into the right window:

```
With Source1 (TaxCode, OwnerTax, OwnerOther, dedCode)
As(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN [Adjdesc] = 'TAX' THEN [TaxCode] ELSE null END AS TaxCode,
CASE WHEN [Adjdesc] = 'TAX' THEN [adj] END AS OwnerTax, 
CASE WHEN [Adjdesc] <> 'TAX' THEN [adj] END AS OwnerOther,
CASE WHEN [Adjdesc] <> 'TAX' THEN [TaxCode] ELSE null END AS dedCode

FROM test4 AS A
WHERE adj IS NOT NULL)

, DATA1 (ID, TaxCode)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TaxCode desc) AS ID, A.TaxCode FROM Source1 A)

, DATA2 (ID, OwnerTax)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ownertax desc) AS ID, A.OwnerTax FROM Source1 A)

, DATA3 (ID, OwnerOther)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OwnerOther desc) AS ID, A.OwnerOther FROM Source1 A)

, DATA4 (ID, DEDCode)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DEDCode desc) AS ID, A.DEDCode FROM Source1 A)

SELECT DATA1.TaxCode, DATA2.OwnerTax, DATA3.OwnerOther, DATA4.DEDCode
FROM DATA1 
LEFT JOIN DATA2 ON DATA1.ID = DATA2.ID
LEFT JOIN Data3 ON DATA1.ID = DATA3.ID
LEFT JOIN Data4 ON DATA1.ID = DATA4.ID
```